# Navbar shifts to the right slightly when dropdown is selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Why does my navbar jump a little to the right when a drop-down is selected? Looks like some padding is missing on :hover perhaps. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

http://www.85widening.com/default.html

Comment: Specifically when one of the drop-down buttons under the Overview button are selected, which triggers a modal. Then you can see the small movement to the right. Any ideas what may cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with Bootstrap hiding the vertical scrollbar on `body` when the modal opens. It occurs only when you have a fixed navbar and body/modal content that require vertical scrolling.

Based on what I recall and found, it's a bug with Bootstrap 3 that I don't believe was ever resolved based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040).

Most workarounds seem to involve JS to add padding-right (like 15px) to the navbar when the modal opens or to override the `overflow: hidden` property the `modal-open` class that Bootstrap adds to `body` when you open a modal. The downside of this is you will have two vertical scroll bars (ugly). Either add the workaround or remove the fixed navbar. I haven't moved on to Bootstrap 4 yet but maybe they've addressed this.